# How to save a long list of images to a specific directory?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How do I save images to a specific directory? It's about 30,000 images that are split in subfolders. I read them with `glob` and `cv2`, added them to a list, then turned them into a NumPy array. Now I'm applying blur and need to add them to a specific directory. All I see is the PIL save example for a single image and it's not working for the list that I have. Any ideas? I converted them to NumPy arrays with this line of code: `images = np.asarray(cv_img)`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def motion_blur(image, degree=21, angle=11):
    image = np.array(image)

    # This generates a matrix of motion blur kernels at any angle. 
    # The greater the degree, the higher the blur.
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((degree / 2, degree / 2), angle, 1)
    motion_blur_kernel = np.diag(np.ones(degree))
    motion_blur_kernel = cv2.warpAffine(motion_blur_kernel, M, (degree, degree))

    motion_blur_kernel = motion_blur_kernel / degree
    blurred = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, motion_blur_kernel)

    # convert to uint8
    cv2.normalize(blurred, blurred, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    blurred = np.array(blurred, dtype=np.uint8)
    return blurred

img_ = motion_blur(images)
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code for the reading and list generation - and regarding the saving, what you've tried so far. Your blurring code is totally irrelevant, and the actual code of interest is missing. Please have a look at how to provide a [mre].

Comment: import cv2
import glob

cv_img = []
for img in glob.glob("/home/data/*/*.jpg"):
    img = cv2.imread(img)
   
    cv_img.append(img)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've saved the desired output in a numpy array, you can use the `imwrite()` method.

For multiple images.

```
import os
import cv2

count=0
DIR="C:\\Name_of_Folder\\"

for i in os.listdir(DIR):
    image=cv2.imread(os.path.join(DIR, i))
    blurred_image = motion_blur(image)
    cv2.imwrite('/path/to/destination/image'+str(count)+'.png',blurred_image) 
    count+=1
```

Comment: kool- thanks! still new to cv2 and how to manipulate images and files of images mostly

Comment: i had to keep reading the file with glob and then just added an extra for loop like i had before but borrowed from you the cv2.imwrite line . thank you!

Comment: count=0
    for i in cv_img:
        img_ = motion_blur(i)
        cv2.imwrite('/home/vanetoj/Documents/data/Train'+str(count)+'.jpg',img_)
    count+=1